# Glass Cast issues after upgrading from Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 10.1.2

Tags: glass-mapper, upgrade

I am trying to migrate Sitecore items from  Sitecore 8.1 to Sitecore 10.1.2. During migration I have got an error as *'Item' does not contain a definition for 'GlassCast' and no accessible extension method 'GlassCast'* Below is my code

```
public IMap GetMapItem()
{
           
     if (this.ContextItem.IsDerived(Templates.Map.ID))
         return this.ContextItem.GlassCast<IMap>();

     return null;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest version of GlassMapper, `GlassCast` method is obsolete with lots of other things. One of the important updates is new contexts which include `IMvcContext`, `IRequestContext`, `IWebFormsContext`. If you want to cast the `Item` type to `IMap`. You cannot simply do it using the `GlassCast` method, You need to create an object of MVC Context (probably the one you will be working on the most), and then needs to code as below-

```
IMvcContext mvcContext = new MvcContext();
var mapItem= mvcContext.GetContextItem<IMap>();
```

The above code is for context item, for any other type of item you can use code as below -

```
IMvcContext mvcContext = new MvcContext();
var mapItem= mvcContext.SitecoreService.GetItem<IMap>(DataSourceItem);
```

Comment: Hi @Mahendra Shekhawat, above code is working.

Comment: @narasimhulu - I am glad it's working, could you please mark this as an answer

Comment: Hi @Mahendra Shekhawat, any solution for this issue:
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/30250/glass-cast-issues-for-contextitem-after-upgrading-from-sitecore-8-1-to-sitecore